# Need to convert column to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, sql-convert

I'm trying to convert an entire column to datetime in BigQuery.  I had to bring it into SQL as string because datetime kept throwing errors.  The current format of my data is

```
Row date_hour
1   4/12/2016 3:00:00 AM
2   4/12/2016 4:00:00 AM
3   4/12/2016 5:00:00 AM
4   4/12/2016 6:00:00 AM
```

I want to convert this to datetime, so I can summarize by days of the week, but all my syntax keeps throwing errors.

I tried:

```
SELECT date_hour
FROM `turing-bebop-390023.Fitness_tracker_data.hourly_steps` 
CONVERT(datetime, date_hour, 100)
LIMIT 1000
```

I admit that I'm very new to SQL, so I don't know exactly how to write the syntax.

Comment: which database system are you using, looks like bigquery? please read up on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter passed to [convert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN) defines how the date string is parsed. The `100` you have is expecting something like `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`. I'd recommend using `101` (for US date formats, that is. For British / European etc, `103` will get the day and month the right way around).

You could try this:

`SELECT CONVERT(datetime, date_hour, 101) FROM turing-bebop-390023.Fitness_tracker_data.hourly_steps`

and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I tried that, but it just says function not found.  Is CONVERT not used in BigQuery?